# javascript: completing action only if a div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.swapImage.swapOut = function() {
        if ($(this).find('.popup').is(':visible') !== true) 
{
    alert(ASDASD)
     $.swapImage.swap(this, "sout");
}
```

I am trying to find if the div "popup+this" (example popup1) is visible before completing the action. Any i ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you post a little bit of your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($(this).find('.popup:visible').length > 0)
```

Comment: The `> 0` is a bit extraneous; if none exist, the length will be `0`.

Comment: Fair enough--I guess I do lean a little more explicit.